# Getting rid of version from JAR file in Maven POM?

Tags: maven, maven-2

In pom.xml, I've below entry which I'm using to create a JAR

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project>
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <groupId>se.sigma.educational</groupId>
   <artifactId>my-jar</artifactId>
   <version>1.0</version>
   <packaging>jar</packaging>
   <name>Executable jar example</name>
     ....
```

Here, everything works fine & JAR gets created with name "my-jar-1.0.jar". Is there a way that I can create the JAR file name as "my-jar.jar" instead of having version within the name??? I tried removing  attribute but then the pom.xml fails to run.

Any help is much appreciated, how do I get rid of version from the JAR file name?

Thanks!

Comment: Why would you like to get rid of the version? This is part of Maven in particular if you like to release the jar file into a Maven repository.

Comment: I agree with khmrbaise. Maven aside, how will people who use your jar know what version it is? How will you know what version your jar is a year from now when you have done three releases? I recommend you reconsider this course of action.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is a `<finalName>` property which lets you define a custom name of an artifact -

```
<build>
        <finalName>NAME_OF_JARFILE</finalName>
</build>
```